How to export data to file CSV in PowerApps
Please tell me about error in this code in code powerapps.
Conditions when select start date & end date and final status when user wants to filter export data.
Thanks and Best Regards,
Mr. Leanghak
Export_CSV.Run(
"StartDate eq '" & S_start_date.SelectedDate & "' and ExpectationDate eq '" & S_end_date.SelectedDate & "'  and FinalStatus eq '" & S_dropdown_status.Selected.Value & "' ",
User().Email
);
The solution to this problem.

Can you check this time a bit?

if your flow in the app has three trigger parameter, two date and a string (the value of your dropdown), the your code should look like this:
FlowCompose.Run(
EndDate.SelectedDate,
StartDate.SelectedDate,
Status.SelectedText.Value)

(the flow name is 'FlowCompose', the two date field is 'EndDate' and 'StartDate', your dropdown input is 'Status')
